# Why isn't the key property recognised as part of the Event type in typescript

Tags: typescript, events, types

I have a function which finds out what button a user pressed using events, and uses the event.key property. However, in the parameter of the function, if i assign it a type Event, the compiler complains that

> Property 'key' does not exist on type 'Event'.

Here is my code.

```
function getDirection(e:Event):void{
    let directionCode:number = e.key; 
    // code going on here
}
```

Why isnt the key property recognised on type event.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Because `Event` does not have that property, `KeyboardEvent` is the class you want.

```
function getDirection(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
    let directionCode:number = e.keyCode; 
    let directionCodeStr:string = e.key; 
    // code going on here
}
```

Comment: Great thanks. So what are the Events properties if every event can be narrowed down like keyboard event or mouse event. When will someone use just event

Comment: @JoeStarbright See MDN: [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).

Answer (score 1):

You should type cast your event:

```
myInput.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    let keyboardEvent = <KeyboardEvent> e;
    if(keyboardEvent.keyCode === 40){
        //...
    }
}
```

Also as the event.kecode is deprecated, you can do:

```
myInput.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    let keyboardEvent = <KeyboardEvent> e;
    if(keyboardEvent.key === 'ArrowDown'){
        //...
    }
}
```